# NGINX - Limit access to folder to a list of user from ldap authentication

Tags: authentication, nginx

A have an nginx reverse proxy behind ldap authentication.
I can read username in php from variable $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']. I think this means that username is passed from ldap to nginx and than to php.
Is it possible in nginx configuration to allow access to a folder only to a list of users?

**UPDATE**
In nginx the user is stored in $remote_user variable. Is it possible to compare $remote_user with a list of users stored in a file? And then deny or allow access to a folder?

**UPDATE**
Probably I have to use ***map*** directive, for example:

```
map $remote_user $allowed_user {
    default 0;
    user1   1;
    user2   1;
}
```

and then test it in the appropriate location:

```
location /folder/ {
    if($allowed_user != 1){
        return 403;
    }
    proxy_pass http://site;
}
```

but when I do `sudo nginx -t`, I receive the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($allowed_user" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:104
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive (please note that `map` translate definitions block should be placed in the **http** context outside the `server` block):

```
map $remote_user $deny
    username1  0;
    username2  0;
    ...
    usernameN  0;
    default    1;
}

server {
    ...
    location /folder/ {
        if ($deny) { return 403; }
        ...
    }
}
```

You can pre-generate users list in the above form (`username1 0; username 2 0; ...`) and then include this list to the nginx configuration:

```
map $remote_user $deny {
    include /path/userlist.txt;
    default 1;
}
```

Whenever this user list file get changed you'd need to reload nginx configuration (`nginx -s reload`).

Comment: Thank you very much! Please read my updates...

Comment: nginx configuration syntax doesn't allow you to skip spaces between `if` directive and its condition. Can't you see by yourself that nginx takes `if($allowed_user` as the whole unknown directive name? Add a space after `if` keyword and everything should be ok.

Comment: Thank you, I added the space and now it works!

Comment: Then you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/tour#:~:text=The%20person%20who%20asked%20can%20mark%20one%20answer%20as%20%22accepted%22.) the answer :) BTW default `map` translation value is an empty string unless something else is specified with the `default` keyword so using your `if` block you can safely remove that `default 0;` line.